# ML Kit stable artifacts depending on preview package (com.google.android.odml.image-1.0.0-beta1)

Tags: google-mlkit

Several latest ML Kit stable packages like:

```
com.google.mlkit.image-labeling-common-17.1.0
com.google.mlkit.object-detection-common-17.1.0
```

and google play service artifacts like:

```
com.google.android.gms.play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-16.3.0
com.google.android.gms.play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning-16.2.0
com.google.android.gms.play-services-mlkit-face-detection-16.2.0
```

depend on prerelease/preview package `com.google.android.odml.image-1.0.0-beta1`

Note: I did not investigate transitive dependencies.

When can release of `com.google.android.odml.image-1.0.0` be expected?

Answer (score 1):

We are actively working on it, but don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: The `com.google.android.odml.image-1.0.0-beta1` is to support an experimental API for image input. If you stay with `InputImage`, the dependency won't be executed in your code path.

Comment: @Shiyu checking poms and it is `compile` scope not `runtime`

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.odml</groupId>
      <artifactId>image</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi molijac, the `MLImage` is exposed in API level so I think we need the `com.google.android.odml.image` at compile time. However if you set the progard correctly I believe all `MLImage` related thing will be stripped and it won't have size impact on your apk. Thanks.